# PHP on getting time before 6:30PM

Tags: php

This is my code below to get. but this code will invalidate the hour before 6PM which minute is above 30, how do I do it that

if today is "3" and today hour is still before 6:30PM , the if condition will works

My current code:

```
if( ($today=="3") &&  ($today_hour < "18") && ($today_min < "30") )
{

}
```

Comment: What does `3` signify in `$today`?

Comment: you are aware that PHP uses SERVER TIME, not LOCAL TIME, right?  if your server runs on ny time, for example, no matter where you are, your code will work for 6 30PM NY TIME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only check the minutes if the hour is actually 6. Change your condition to:

```
if ($today == 3 && ($today_hour < 18 || ($today_hour == 18 && $today_min < 30))) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Or easier to read:

```
$beforeTime = $today_hour < 18 || ($today_hour == 18 && $today_min < 30);

if ($today == 3 && $beforeTime) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Make sure to work with numbers as well, because doing string comparison on them will lead to unexpected results when the amount of digits is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you :

```
   if ((date('d') == "03") && (date('H') < "18:30")) {
       $condition = true;
    }
```

H = 24-hour format of an hour (00 to 23)